# I want to give limit to Text input in python/kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So I made game with `python` and `kivy` where you must enter team name. When you enter team name it transfers to the next class with "submit" button. If user types more then 9 characters button must be disabeld. The problem is if you enter long name, on the next class things are pretty ugly. So I want to give textinput a limit in `kivy` file. Here's my `kivy` code:

```
TextInput:
        id: teamI_name
        font_name: 'bpg_nino_mtavruli_bold'
        text: "Type Name"
        size_hint: .5, .05
        multiline: False
        font_size: 80
        pos_hint: {'x': .45, 'y': .57}
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        foreground_color: 0, 0, 255, 1

Button:
        text: "start"
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        size_hint: .43, .1
        pos_hint: {'x': .4, 'y': .1}
        on_press: root.submit_on()
        on_release: root.submit_off()
        disabled: True if team1_name.text == '' or team2_name.text == '' else False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day. You could create a common variable in your `App` class so that your widgets in kv file could refer to. I recommend you use a [Property](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html) (especially a [string property](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.Property)).

So in your `App` class, you could add `team_name_str = StringProperty()`.

In your kv script, you assign `teamI_name` with text: `text:app.team_name_str`

The logic for your start button will then be `disabled: bool(team1_name.text) or bool(team2_name.text) or len(team2_name.text)>9`

Comment: Thanks! Your answer really helped me.❤